# Android studio on Mac El Capitan - issues in setting up the SDK

Tags: macos, osx-el-capitan, android-studio

Having issues while trying to set-up Android Studio (latest release, 2.3) on a Mac (El Capitan 10.11.3). Studio is installed, but when I launch it a window for configuring the SDK appears, and after a few passages I get this error:

"An error occurred while trying to compute required packages"﻿

Anyone got this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the answer to my problem.  So, to recap...

- It seems that Android Studio does not include the command line tools anymore. This is contrary to what stated on the web page for the download of AS. In any case, as suggested in the other answer to this question, first I downloaded the .zip package containing the command line tools (bottom of AS download page) and extracted it in .../android/sdk (the ... is any path you like for the Android components; in my case I am on a Mac and selected /usr/local/). This results in a subfolder called tools.
- If you run the wizard, it doesn't work - oh well, to be honest I didn't try with the custom option, which allows selecting the directory for the sdk; maybe this would allow the wizard to see the sdk manager, which is in tools/bin. Anyway, I entered AS and selected, on the bottom, the "configure" button. From the drop-down menu, "SDK manager". It prompts for an SDK location. Clicked "edit". Selected as location .../android/sdk. A warning says that no SDK is installed. I tried to go ahead anyway, and successfully installed the sdk (requires some time).
- Now, upon restart of AS, the setup wizard won't pop up anymore. But there's a further error: at the bottom of the initial window, a dialog appears saying there are updates for the tools. If you try to install them, you encounter an error (many others noticed this on SuperUser - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42732684/dependant-package-with-key-emulator-not-found-while-updating-android-sdk-and-too) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42733995/android-studio-error-an-error-occurred-while-trying-to-compute-required-package/42735118#42735118)). The error is due to a dependence of the tools from the emulator, which has not been installed. Others suggest to use the sdkmanager from the command line to install the emulator, but this didn't work for me since I don't have any Java Development Kit installed yet, and the sdkmanager from command line requires it. So, I did this: clicked again the "configure" button, selected "Preferences", and then from the tree which appears on the left selected "Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Updates". Here switched, for the update check, from "Stable Channel" to "Canary Channel" (seems, based on suggestions on StackExchange, that the emulator is only there). Clicked "Check Now". Refused to install updates for the tools. Then selected, on the tree on the left, "Android SDK", and there, the tab "SDK Tools". At this point the Emulator appeared, I selected it, applied settings, and this installed the Emulator and the Tool update from the Canary Channel. Clearly this means that they are less stable, but this is it. Went back to "Updates" and selected again the "Stable Channel".

Answer (score 0):

After an update Android studio was not working. So I have uninstalled it and deleted all the local folders related to Android studio. I have tried to install it again but I had faced the same issue.

After some research, I have found out that Android studio was looking for `sdkmanager` and it is a part of android tools. I have downloaded `sdkmanager` and extracted it in `/Users/<loggeduser>/Library/Android/sdk` folder as tools. This solved the problem and wizard downloaded 1.5GB data.

Comment: What update version are you talking about (be specific)? What source you have used to download sdkmanager (provide a link or reference)?